# How to unflatten a JSON object?

Tags: json, object, nested, jq

How to convert the flattened JSON like following

```json
{
  "foo.bar1": "1",
  "foo.bar2": "2",
  "foo.bar3.doo1": "3",
  "foo.bar3.doo2" : "4"
}
```

to be nested like

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "bar1": "1",
    "bar2": "2",
    "bar3": {
      "doo1": "3",
      "doo2": "4"
    }
  }
}
```

? I could find many posts about flattening a nested JSON, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert keys to paths, and put the values in their original places using [`setpath`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#setpath(PATHS;VALUE)).

```
. as $in | reduce keys_unsorted[] as $k ({}; setpath($k / "."; $in[$k]))
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/v4Mat2Wgay)</sup>